# javascript - window.onload is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

What I am trying to do is a tool in which it will export a pdf file.

There are two cases:

1. I don't have to check for anything and directly after the user clicks the export button it will open a new blank window because I am using headers to download the file and after the blank page is finished loading, it will close.

script for case 1

```
$('body').on("click", '.export-invoice-pdf', function () {
    // get id
    let id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    let newWindow = window.open(
        'url' + id,
        "_blank"
    );
    newWindow.onload = function() {
        newWindow.close();
    };
});
```

### This works fine

---

2. I have to check if there is an available pdf file for the entry. before opening a new blank window to have the file and then close it afterwards just like in case1

script for case 2:

```
$('body').on("click", '.export-invoice-pdf', function () {
    // get id
    let id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    let newWindow = window.open(
        '',
        "_blank"
    );
    //Ajax call to check if there is an available file
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: {'orderId': orderId},
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true,
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log('1');
        if (data.hasFile === true) {
            //if has file do the samething as case 1
            newWindow.location.href = 'url' + orderId;
            newWindow.onload = function() {
                 newWindow.close();
            };
        } else {
            alert('no file to export');
        }
    }).error(function () {
    });
});
```

Now this is not working. Actually my first problem was it's not making the new window because it treats it as a popup but I got that fixed after an hour of research. Now the closing of the window is my problem.

I have looked it up already in and still currently looking not just in here but sadly I was not able to find an answer about this problem. Any kind of help is appreciated.

---

**Update:** The thing that worked for me is by using XMLHttpRequest so that I don't have to open a new blank tab so that my php headers will serve me the PDF file.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //we use responseType arraybuffer so that the pdf file won't be blank
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type:"application/pdf"});
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "nameofpdf.pdf";
            link.click();
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

The url that I used was handled by a controller that gives me the pdf file still with the use of php headers.

Comment: why not open new window after success of ajax?

Comment: @AndrejsGubars because if I place it the same in what I did in case1 it will treat is as a popup and it will be blocked. the thing that I did was a work-around for it. which where also used by others.

Comment: problem is opening up the window without it being a webpage sort of kills your ability to do anything with it. Any reason you are not just putting it into an iframe?

Comment: @AndrejsGubars can you print 'newWindow' value on console and see it is defined or not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup blockers usually don't allow popups (or programmatically clicking dynamically created hyperlinks etc) if `window.open()` is not invoked by a direct user action. Every browser has a slightly different mechanism of blocking popups.

In your case 1, first all code is run on the main thread as a result of user clicking the export button. This works fine.

In case 2 opening a window may not work in all browsers as it is called from another thread. Ajax success handler will be called asynchronously long after your onclick event finished.

To correct this, you can use synchronous requests to execute all code on main thread.
You can [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) or async option `$.ajax({async: false})`. It ensure that you code will work in all browsers as they change their popup blocking algorithms.

Implementing above suggestions can help fix your issue with `window.onload()` not being triggered, but there is another improvement that can be made - adding `onload` handler before navigation:

```
//if has file do the samething as case 1
newWindow.onload = function() {
     newWindow.close();
};
newWindow.location.href = 'url' + orderId;
```

Or even better add it in the main thread, right after

```
let newWindow = window.open(
    '',
    "_blank"
);
newWindow.onload = function() {
     newWindow.close();
};
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was quite late to view this post again. but the think that I got working is using the XMLHttpRequest so that I don't have to open a new tab to download a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$('body').on("click", '.export-invoice-pdf', function () {
    //Ajax call to check if there is an available file
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: {'orderId': orderId},
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true,
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log('1');
        if (data.hasFile === true) {
            //if has file do the samething as case 1
            // get id
            const id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
            Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
                target: '_blank',
                'url' + orderId,
            }).click();
            // make user close the tab
        } else {
            alert('no file to export');
        }
    }).error(function () {
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this one and sadly it won't open a new tab and then browser would say that the popup is blocked.

Comment: @Josefph you can't prevent the browser from blocking popups - it's a helpful browser feature made for the users. After the first time it is blocked you can enable it and it won't be blocked again on the same domain.

Comment: @Shahar The code that I have is working it will open the blank window and download the needed file. The only problem is when closing the newly opened window

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work. Are you getting errors in the console? I would try to place `let newWindow` outside of the function to make sure it's not a scope issue first.

Comment: @Josefph I think the reason it doesn't work is that by the time you register the `newWindow.onload` event it may already happened. Meaning `newWindow.close();` will never get called.
Instead, you can register `newWindow.close();` right after calling `window.open()` and decide to handle it later - for example set a variable `shouldCloseWIndow = true` and then check that variable on `if (data.hasFile === true)` first.

Comment: @Shahar first of all thanks for the help, Yes I already placed the newWindow variable outside of the function. and I also think that I am registering the event when it is happening or happened already.

Comment: @Shahar what do you mean on setting a variable shouldCloseWindow = true?

Comment: @Josefph I meant you could create a variable that will hold a boolean state that decides if the window should be close or not.
However, I'm trying to understand what exactly are you trying to achieve and why would you open a blank window on click and change its' location later? why not open it when you already know the link it should be opened with?
Check Andrejs' answer, it may be a better solution.

Comment: @Shahar Thanks for the reply, It's actually stated on top that I am opening the a blank window so that I could download a file by using headers in php. Andrejs's answer let's the user close the window what I am trying to achieve is to close the window after is it loaded (after the file has been served/downloaded). I am changing it's location later because if I do it right away the same script with the one on case 1 the browser would treat it as a popuo and block it. because you can only use window.open when it's triggered by a user action the that's why by directly doing it it is working.

Comment: @Shahar but what I am doing right now is I have to check if the entry has a file that's why I am using ajax and calling the window.open there. and it works it would open a new blank window and then serve the file but now the problem is I can't close the window/.

Comment: @Josefph I added an answer using iframe. I believe it's a better solution for your problem and should work cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using iframe for this. It's a perfectly valid solution and would prevent the need to listen to another window event, which is bad practice and not needed.

```
function downloadFile(fileUrl) {
        var downloadIframe = $('#download-iframe');
        if (downloadIframe) {
              downloadIframe.remove();
        }
        $('<iframe>', {
            id: 'download-iframe',
            src: fileURL
        }).hide().appendTo('body');
}
```